# Why isn't mod, is_int and ctype_digit working as expected in my scenario?

Tags: php

I have numbers coming through that I'm checking whether or not their divisible is a number without leaving over any decimal places. I.e. I check if the number is divisible by 9, 8, 7, 6.75, etc. I don't want to use regex.

Examples
mod (my preferred choice)

```
if (344.25 % 6.75 == 0) {
  print_r("No decimals"); //Should print because the calculation is 51, a whole number?
}
```

is_int

```
if (is_int(344.25/6.75)) {
  print_r("No decimals"); //Should also print?
}
```

ctype_digit

```
if (ctype_digit(344.25/6.75)) {
  print_r("No decimals"); //Should also print?
}
```

I've also tried `is_numeric` with no luck either.

Comment: See this https://3v4l.org/I8aYM Works as expected, your expectation is wrong. Modulo returns 2 and division returns float.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Ah, so I'll have to do a division and then check if it's a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using `if(ctype_digit(strval(344.25/6.75))) {...}` and it's working well.